# Return list of Dictionary from UDF pyspark

Tags: python, arrays, apache-spark, dictionary, pyspark

I have a list of Dictionaries like below:

```
department_amount_pairs = [{"department_1": 100},{"department_2": 200},{"department_1": 300}]
```

What I am currently doing is

```
def department_udf(department_amount_pairs ):
    pair = []
    for d in department_amount_pairs:
         pair.append(json.dumps(d))
    return pair
```

This is my udf definition

```
extractor = udf(department_udf,ArrayType(StringType()))
spark.udf.register("extractor_udf", extractor)
```

This is how I call this function

```
data = data.withColumn('pairs',extractor_udf('department_amount'))
```

It returns JSON object.. **"**[{"department_1": 100},{"department_2": 200},{"department_1": 300}]**"**
I have to do json.loads() to extract this array.. But I want my udf to return an **Array** of **Dictionaries**

I tried without json.dumps and appended dictionary into list. But I get NONE value..I also tried to change return type to just ArrayType(ArrayType()) it didnt work either...

Answer (score 0):

You can return array of dictionaries by specifying the UDF type as `array<map<string,int>>`.

For example,

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf

def department_udf():
    return [{"department_1": 100},{"department_2": 200},{"department_1": 300}]

extractor = udf(department_udf, 'array<map<string,int>>')

df = spark.range(1)

df.withColumn('pairs', extractor()).show(truncate=False)
+---+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
|id |pairs                                                                |
+---+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
|0  |[[department_1 -> 100], [department_2 -> 200], [department_1 -> 300]]|
+---+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: I tried doing it.. But when I dump it to to parquet.. Instead of Dictionary I get Tuples

Comment: There is no `dictionary` type in Spark/Parquet. You may be referring to structs, but struct cannot be used inside an array if they have different fields (e.g. department_1, department_2). You need to use a map for this purpose...

Comment: lets say if i have just one dictionary{"department_1": 100, "department_2": 200,"department_3": 300} and I want this dictionary only in 1 row. So in UDF what i do is return type = map<string,int>. Then i dump it into parquet.. When I read it it has become tupple- [("department_1": 100), ( "department_2", 200), ("department_3", 300)] How can I get just the Map (dictionary) back?

Comment: Hmm... I thought parquet supports map type. I can write a map type to parquet and read it back succesffully.Could you show the code you used to read and write?

Comment: one thing i missed in my previous comment was.. I am reading parquet using pd.read_parquet('filename.parquet').. If i read in spark yes I can see the map type..But i want it to be read in Pandas

Comment: pandas doesn't support parquet very well, compared to spark. Maybe you can read with spark then convert `.toPandas()`?

Comment: I have a huge file, I cannot use toPandas(). Any other workarounds?

Comment: If you have a huge file, you couldn't read it with pandas anyway, so why would you worry about pandas being unable to read it as dictionary?